# System of Differential Equations for Particular Initial Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I want to solve the following system of differential equations:
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t) = x(t) + y(t) \\
y'(t) = y(t)
\end{cases}$$

With the intial conditions $x(0) = 1$ and $y(0) = 1.$
Obviously, $y(t)$ (as well as $y'(t)$) are equal to $e^t$.

How do I find $x(t)$ now?

I have tried the following:

$x'(t) = x(t) + y(t)$ can be written as
$y(t) = x'(t) - x(t).$

Now we know that $x(0)$ and $y(0) = 1$, hence:
$1 = x'(0) - 1, \therefore x'(0) = 2.$

How do I proceed from here (if it makes sense to proceed from here)?

Comment: You have solved the equation for $y(t)$, now substitute into the equation for $x(t)$, i.e. $x' = x + e^{t}$. This is a first-order linear equation. You can solve it using an integrating factor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've found that $y(t)=e^t$, then you can plug it in to the formula for $x$, in order to get that $x'(t)=x(t)+e^t$, which is a linear ODE, and therefore, you can begin by solving the homogenous ODE $x'(t)=x(t)$, and then use variation or some other method to solve the non-homogenous ODE.

Comment: Ok, the solution then for x'(t) = x(t) is e^t. With this method I get that the helper function g(t) in x'(t) - f(t)*x(t) = g(t) with x'(t) - x(t) = e^t. Then I use x'(t) = C'(t)*e^t, hence C'(t) = 1, and with the formula x'(t) = C'(t)*e^t - C(t)*e^t I arrive at x'(t) = e^t - t*e^(t)...hm, I think I have a mistake, right? Also, where would I use the initial conditions?

Comment: You write out $x(t)=C(t)e^t$, and then differentiate, in order to get $x'(t)=C'(t)e^t+e^tC(t)=e^t(C'(t)+C(t)$. On the other hand, we have the original ODE, which gives you that $x'(t)=x(t)+e^t=C(t)e^t+e^t=e^t(C(t)+1)$, and then, you can solve $e^t(C'(t)+C(t))=e^t(C(t)+1)$, such that, $C'(t)+C(t)=C(t)+1$, and therefore, $C'(t)=1$, and through integration, $C(t)=x+c$. Plug this into the solution, in order to get that $x(t)=(x+c)e^t$, and then plug in the initial conditions to solve.

Comment: Great, hence then C(t) = t. But why didn't I have to use the initial conditions anywhere?

Comment: You use the initial conditions in the end, when you plug in $x(0)=1$ to the formula $x(t)=(t+c)e^t$, in order to get that $1=x(0)=ce^0=c$, and then you will get that $c=1$.